# Determine unique device ID (e.g. serial number) for identical USB devices

Tags: python, windows, winapi, gps, pywin32

I have multiple identical [GPS logging devices](http://www.qstarz.com/Products/GPS%20Products/BT-Q1300ST-F.htm) that I can transfer the tracking data with the command line using [GPSBabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/).

**Question: Using Python 2.7, Windows 7, and these GPS logging devices, how can I identify each identical device, uniquely and repeatedly?** A good example would be a serial number, which is unique for each identical devices (and physically printed on the device).

I'm working with a Python 2.7 and Windows 7 (must be Windows and not Linux because of drivers).

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

When two devices are plugged into USB ports, the device manager shows the following for **Ports (COM & LPT)**. (The USB devices are **not** mounted as USB disks.)

[image]

(Ports 8 and 10)

Selecting **Properties** - **Details** of the device on Port 10 gives me one unique looking ID, called **ContainerID**, but I can't programmatically find any unique ID like a serial number for multiple, identical devices.

[image]

Using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9087586/2327328),

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_SerialPort"):
    if usb.Name.startswith('GPS'):
        print usb.DeviceID, usb.Name, usb.PNPDeviceID
```

I get this response:

```
COM10 GPS USB Serial Interface Driver (COM10) USB\VID_0E8D&PID_3329\6&21C2E9BE&0&1
COM8 GPS USB Serial Interface Driver (COM8) USB\VID_0E8D&PID_3329\6&25E9E978&0&3
```

(Not unique! the trailing ID `6&21C2E9BE&0&1` is actually related to the port, and not the device. I can test this by taking the same device and running the code with just 1 device connected, or 2 devices connected.)

I can find this number in the Device Manager / Details view under *Device Instance Path*

[image]

I've gone through the [Win32 API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394413(v=vs.85).aspx) the options for Win32_SerialPort, and some others. I can't find any API class that returns anything that is unique, like a serial number.

[image]

Comment: It'd depend on the devices themselves too. unless it itself has some unique manufacture-determined software-accessible value burned into it somewhere, there WON'T be any way to differentiate between two instances of the same device. e.g. on a network card, you can (hopefully/usually) depend on the MAC address being different. if your gps devices' only difference, electrically/software-wise is that they came in different boxes, then there's no way to tell which one is which if you ever unplug/shuffle them/replug.

Comment: If this is the case, is there any way that I can assign ID to the device? (Or is that a separate question?)

Comment: you can probably assign anything you want, but where would this be stored? If there's no writable "memory" on the device, that id would be LOST when unplugged. If you have device P in port X, and Q->Y, what happens if they get unplugged and get replugged as P->Y and Q->X? without any device-side storage, there'll  be absolutely NO way to tell that they've been swapped.

Comment: If I have 2 USB ports, X and Y, and I label them X and Y, and then always plug P into X and Q into Y, will the devices be assigned the same COM Port? To make it more complicated, I'll need external USB hubs for multiple devices.

Comment: that I can't answer. I have no idea what/how windows enumerates things as they get pluggedin.

Comment: This is why Windows uses the port they're plugged into as a part of the device ID. As others have said, if the devices are identical, they're identical. If it's important that they're not you need to find another device.

Comment: The COM ports won't remain the same, but you should be able to find which USB port a device is plugged into, Then your previous solution of always plugging into the same port should work. Find your devices, find the USB port, find the current assigned COM port for that USB port and then open the COM port assigned.

Comment: @topshot - can you expand your comment as an answer? So far I've connected a USB hub to the same USB port, and then 10 devices to marked ports on the hub. The COM and USB identification numbers, as a pair, have remained the same (so far)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten around to writing any code for that yet. I just know I've had the COM ports assigned to a given USB port switch on me for no reason. I also expect I'll have to deal with identical hardware at some point as you are since I've had to in the past (using real COM ports, not USB). In my search to solve this future issue I've come across code that pulls out the actual USB port description. So my intent will be to store what specific USB port scanner 3 is on for example instead of what COM port it uses. From that USB port see what COM port is currently assigned and open it.

Comment: And my code would be VB.Net anyway, not python. I was looking far and wide for any better solutions to this issue that someone may have come across.