# check if specific device is connected to COM Port

Tags: python, generator, pyserial

I want to check if one specific device is connected to one of my serial ports.

with `list_ports.comports()` I get all the COM Ports

 with  `x = list_ports.grep("0403:6001")`
I can search for a specific device. This gives me

`<class 'serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo'>` output.

But I just want an a bolean expression as an output if this device is connected or not

I have read this answer, but it didnt solve my problem [Pyserial get the name of the device behind a COM Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756695/python-how-to-detect-device-name-id-on-a-serial-com/9087586)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the manual](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.grep) `.grep()` returns an iterable of `ListPortInfo`s, and I assume it'd return nothing if there was no matching device connected.

To get from an iterable to a boolean, the built-in `any()` is your friend:

```py
device_connected = any(list_ports.grep("0403:6001"))
```